# No Launcher activity found! - Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am getting a `No Launcher activity found!` error while launching my Andoid Application. My `AndroidManifest.xml` file has a LAUNCHER tag defined. I am not clear why I am getting this error though.

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.test.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.Class1"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
       <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.Class2"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
 </application>
```

Can anyone advise the cause for this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<action android:name="com.example.test.MAIN" />
```

with

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```